# JavaScript: Setting the style property on a div tag in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, internet-explorer-7, dynamic-data

I am trying to dynamically create a `div` tag in JavaScript and place it in an existing `div` tag.

This code works fine on FF, Chrome, IE9 and IE10. The code needs to work in IE7.

When setting the style property, IE7 throws the following error:

> Not implemented

Here is the code:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="content"> </div>
      <script> 
         var input = document.createElement('div');

         // Above code above executes fine.
         input.style = "display: block;";  // << This code triggers
                                           // the error mentioned above

         input.className = "container";
         input.innerHTML = 'Test';
         var container = document.getElementById('content');
         container.appendChild(input);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if I am overlooking something here or if this code needs to be changed when running in IE7. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you setting a div's style to `display:block` when that is the default? And why are you setting inline styles when you're adding a class to the div - why not just include all needed styles in the class? Anyway, regarding the error, have you tried appending the div to the container first, and then setting style? Or `input.style.display = "block";`?

Comment: @nnnnnn The code changes the inline styles as required further down the line. This has already been coded and I am trying to make it compatible with IE7. Tried appending the `div` to the container and then setting the style. Same result. `input.style.display = "block";` also gives an error `Could not get the display property. Invalid argument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
input.style.display = "block";
```

Though I wonder why you're trying to do this at all because `block` is already the default display style for a `<div>` element.

Comment: When I try `input.style.display = "block;";` it gives the error: `Could not get the display property. Invalid argument.`

Comment: @slayernoah - something else must be going on then in your document because this form of addressing the style property works fine in IE 7.

Comment: It does work. Thanks!! I was trying `input.style.display = "block;";` instead of `input.style.display = "block";`. It's been a long day! Thank you!